# How to deal with response while receiving it from server ( $http.get ) to avoid memory leak in mobile?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, memory-leaks

I make a  http get request to nodejs server and the response from the server is too big, so my app gets crashed because of memory warning leak.

Can I write the response to local storage file while receiving it from the server?

EDIT: the application have to load data from the server depending on the user, I make a http get request to the server then wait for the response now before the code even reach the success or the fail methods the application hang and sometimes even crash and close, when I monitored the process in xcode it showed the app using over 500mb of the memory and then a memory warning appeared before the hang/crash.

the response is JSON object and can be large (in mb's) cuz it contain thousands of objects including base64 images

the code used to work fine with smaller JSON response and when I try it in Postman now the program crash but that is a reported problem for Postman with large responses afaik.

this is the part of code i make the request with:

```
$http.get(URL,{
headers: {
  "Authorization": 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
  "x-access-token": Token
}}).then(function (response) { //Sucess });
```

Comment: What do you mean with ' a too big response'? Is it JSON? Or what is the format? How big is it? Filesize? JSON object size? What is a memory leak according to your findings? Does your application hang? ... Please provide some more information...

Comment: yes JSON response,
Received memory warning.
2017-02-06 11:11:56.973 SalesPerson[2674:613299] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x19a157a80> { count = 1, contents =

"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x19a157e78> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }

}>

Comment: How many KB is the response? Can you access your REST method through ex. Postman?  Are you using sockets? It's hard to help you with this limited information...

Comment: I updated the question with more details answering your questions, any help would be appreciated